# Item preview fails with "Section or group name 'system.web.webPages.razor' is already defined"

Tags: configuration, coveo, razor

I've created a Coveo search page using the reference here: https://developers.coveo.com/display/public/SitecoreV4/Inserting+and+Customizing+a+Search+Interface+Component. When I try to preview it, I get the following error:

```
Error rendering the following component: Default

System.InvalidOperationException:
 Error while rendering view: '/Views/Coveo/SearchViewLayout.cshtml'.
 ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Section or 
group name 'system.web.webPages.razor' is already defined. Updates to 
this may only occur at the configuration level where it is defined. 
(C:\Sitecore\dev.[obfuscated].org\Website\views\coveo\web.config line 6)
   at 
System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean 
ignoreLocal)
   at 
System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(ConfigurationSchemaErrors
 schemaErrors)
   at 
System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String 
configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean 
getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object&
 resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String 
configKey)
   at System.Web.Configuration.RuntimeConfig.GetSectionObject(String 
sectionName)
   at System.Web.Configuration.RuntimeConfig.GetSection(String 
sectionName, Type type, ResultsIndex index)
   at System.Web.Configuration.RuntimeConfig.get_Compilation()
   at 
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.IsBatchEnabledForDirectory(VirtualPath
 virtualDir)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath 
virtualPath)
   at 
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath
 virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean 
allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean 
ensureIsUpToDate)
   at 
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext
 context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean 
allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, 
Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at 
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath
 virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean 
throwIfNotFound)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType(VirtualPath 
virtualPath)
   at 
Jabberwocky.Glass.Autofac.Mvc.Pipelines.Processors.GetModelFromViewProcessor.GetModel(GetModelArgs
 args, String path)
   at 
Jabberwocky.Glass.Autofac.Mvc.Pipelines.Processors.GetModelFromViewProcessor.Run(GetModelArgs
 args)
   at 
Jabberwocky.Glass.Autofac.Pipelines.Processors.ProcessorBase`1.Process(T
 pipelineArgs)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String 
pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at 
Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs,TResult](String
 pipelineName, TArgs args, Func`2 resultGetter)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.Rendering.GetModel()
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.Rendering.get_Model()
   at 
Sitecore.Mvc.Extensions.ObjectExtensions.ValueOrDefault[T,TResult](T 
source, Func`2 resultGetter)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.get_Model()
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
   at 
Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer
 renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)
   at 
AOPA.Library.CustomSitecore.Pipelines.RenderRenderings.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer
 renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args) in 
c:\Dev\AOPA\web2.0\src\AOPA.Library\CustomSitecore\Pipelines\RenderRenderings\ExecuteRenderer.cs:line
 18
```

Other items appear correctly in Preview mode. In the logs, there is no additional information; same error. It looks like I have this section in multiple files in the following locations:

```
Views
Views\Coveo
Views\Coveo Hive
sitecore\shell\client
layouts\Coveo Hive
Coveo\Hive\templates
Areas\Social\Views
Areas\Aopa\Views
Areas\Admin\Views
```

I do not have a Razor sectionGroup in my main web.config. I would rather not provide the web.config because it has sensitive data in it.

I've tried adding `<remove name="system.web.webPages.razor"/>` before the sectionGroup definition but that does nothing.

**Views/Web.config**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
          <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
          <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
      </configSections>

      <system.web.webPages.razor>
        <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
          <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
          </namespaces>
        </pages>
      </system.web.webPages.razor>

      <appSettings>
        <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
      </appSettings>

      <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
          <remove name="BlockViewHandler" />
          <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
        </handlers>
      </system.webServer>
      <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Castle.Core" publicKeyToken="407dd0808d44fbdc" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.3.0.0" newVersion="3.3.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Autofac" publicKeyToken="17863af14b0044da" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="MiniProfiler" publicKeyToken="b44f9351044011a3" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.2.0.157" newVersion="3.2.0.157" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.2.0.0" newVersion="1.2.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http.Cors" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="HtmlAgilityPack" publicKeyToken="bd319b19eaf3b43a" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.4.6.0" newVersion="1.4.6.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http.WebHost" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="AngleSharp" publicKeyToken="e83494dcdc6d31ea" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-0.9.4.42449" newVersion="0.9.4.42449" />
          </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
      </runtime>

    </configuration>
```

**Views/Coveo/Web.config**

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <remove name="system.web.webPages.razor"/>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
    </httpHandlers>

    <!--
        Enabling request validation in view pages would cause validation to occur
        after the input has already been processed by the controller. By default
        MVC performs request validation before a controller processes the input.
        To change this behavior apply the ValidateInputAttribute to a
        controller or action.
    -->
    <pages
        validateRequest="false"
        pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <controls>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coveo for Sitecore 4.1 came with Web.configs that referenced `System.Web.WebPages.Razor V2.0.0.` My project uses 3.0.0. I had to update the version in the following files to 3.0.0:

```
Views/Coveo/Web.config
Views/Coveo Hive/Web.config
layouts/Coveo Hive
Coveo/Hive/templates
```